# The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x14ddbdc0 V:[UIToolbar:0x14dbb790]-(0)-[_UIKBCompatInputView:0x14df6a30]>

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm having problem in my iOS8 project when I switch from one UItextField to another with inputAccessoryView from XIB.

The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: 
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.

2014-10-06 12:26:12.656 [722:184153] *** Assertion failure in -[UIInputSetHostView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.0.1/NSLayoutConstraint_UIKitAdditions.m:558

2014-10-06 12:26:12.658 [722:184153] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
currentTextField = textField;
keyBoardToolBar.hidden = NO;

textField.inputAccessoryView = keyBoardToolBar;
[keyBoardToolBar removeFromSuperview];
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
if (IDIOM != IPAD)
    medicationTableVIew.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 240, 0);
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
[keyBoardToolBar removeFromSuperview];
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: When you setup a constraint e.g. [self.parentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithVisualFormat:@H:|[subView1[subView2]|" ...]; the subviews need to be a child of "self.parentView" in this case. The other cause for this is you haven't added subview to the parent view using [self.parentView addSubview:self.subview]; Another thing I found is keyboard input accessory view doesn't play well with constraints. It only seems to work with frames from my own experience.

Comment: **Thanks Zhang**. I have resolved this by creating inputAccessoryView ToolBar programmatically by subclassing UIToolBar.